# What level do I cast invisibility from the eldritch invocation Shroud of Shadow?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, unearthed-arcana

The eldritch invocation Shroud of Shadow from the [*UA: Revised Class Options*](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/revised-class-options) reads as follows:

> You can cast *invisibility* at will, without expending a spell slot.

Similar abilities such as a wizard's spell mastery specify that the caster can only cast the at-will spells at their lowest spell level:

> You can cast those [at will] spells at their lowest level without expending a spell slot when you have them prepared.

Shroud of Shadow has no such clause. So can this *invisibility* spell be cast at a higher level?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Shroud of Shadows is an eldritch invocation in the Revised Class Options Unearthed Arcana.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Cool. I made a few edits if you want to take a look.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I know you're right about spells, they're not actually capitalized, but I actually think Eldritch Invocations are capitalized and not italicized because they're class features. They're at least capitalized when Crawford mentions them in a Tweet: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/610957214849835008

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61521/discussion-between-rob-rose-and-hey-i-can-chan).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spells cast without a spell slot are cast at their lowest level. And no, you can't cast it at a higher level because to do so would require you to expend a higher level spell slot.

From page 12 of the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> **What level is a spell if you cast it without a spell slot?**
>   Such a spell is cast at its lowest possible level, which is the level that appears near the top of its description. Unless you have a special ability that says otherwise, the only way to increase the level of a spell is to expend a higher-level spell slot when you cast it

Comment: thanks for the info in the sage advice compendium. i looked at their website and searched for something that could tell me but couldn't find any hits. didnt think to look in the compendium.

Comment: As ne being new to Warlocks, this was extremely helpful.